Laravel 11 / Vue - 404 not found when force deleting a soft deleted model via route model binding and utilising destroy()
When I am trying to forceDelete() a soft deleted model through route model binding I am getting 404 not found. This only happens when force deleting a model and not when restoring or soft deleting. I have set the edit method to restore the model if it's being edited and it was trashed and this works correctly via route model binding (see below code).
RecipeController.php
//this works as intended
public function edit(Recipe $recipe)
{
    Gate::authorize('update', $recipe);

    if ($recipe->trashed()) {
        $recipe->restore();
    }

    return Inertia::render('Recipes/Edit', [
        'recipe' => $recipe->load(['ingredients', 'steps', 'categories']),
        'categories' => Auth::user()->categories
    ]);
}

I have also tried dd($recipe); in the destroy method before the Gate::authorize(); to see if that was playing up but I still get 404 not found.
I'd like to keep it all in the standard routes and have destroy() work out if it should be permanently deleted or soft deleted. Do I have to create an additional method to handle force deletes and just pass in an id?
web.php
Route::resource('/recipes', RecipeController::class)->withTrashed();

RecipeController.php
//this does not work and returns 404 when force deleting it works fine for soft deleting
public function destroy(Recipe $recipe)
{
   Gate::authorize('delete', $recipe);
        
   if ($recipe->trashed()) {
       $recipe->forceDelete();
       Storage::deleteDirectory('recipe-images/'.$recipe->id);
   } else {
       $recipe->delete();
   }
}

Index.vue
<Link :href="route('recipes.destroy', recipe)" method="delete" as="button" class="relative inline-flex w-0 flex-1 items-center justify-center gap-x-3 rounded-br-lg border border-transparent py-3 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900">
    <TrashIcon class="h-5 w-5 text-red-400" aria-hidden="true" />
</Link>

php artisan route:list
DELETE recipes/{recipe} recipes.destroy › RecipeController@destroy

console error
DELETE http://127.0.0.1:8000/recipes/9c8fa4c7-8723-4ca4-8468-5968ae7c02e3 404 (Not Found)


I believe you are running into the issue of laravel's route-model binding. At this point the initial query when you reach your controller laravel will filter out deleted records. You should either change your route-model-binding to avoid this or don't bind your parameter to your model in the controller and manually query your record.
